# Call a handlebars helper from a rendered template

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using a helper method to render a template, like so:

```
module.exports = (Handlebars) => {
  Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', () => {
    var template = require('../path/to/template.hbs')
    return template;
  })
}
```

In the rendered template, I'd like to call another helper, `bar`.

```
// template.hbs
<div>
  {{foo}}
</div>

// bar.js
module.exports = (Handlebars) => {
  Handlebars.registerHelper('bar', ()=> {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

But the rendered template seems to have no visibility of the helper, i.e. `bar` isn't called. What's a good way to get around this?

Comment: Why don't you include template.hbs using {{> template  }}? Then it would see your bar helper. And you wouldn't need foo helper

Comment: @Molda oh using a partial? Looks promising. I'll give it a try.